# How to make a trait available to an object

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am learning Scala from Martin Odersky's book "Programming in Scala". In his "Packages and Imports" Chapter there is an example that Martin has in which he is demonstrating how import clauses work. To test my understanding of import clauses in Scala, I created a  source file called Vegetable.scala  in Eclipse under the Scala perspective.This code is identical to Martin's code, except that I changed the name of the trait from Fruit to Vegetable and the name of the object from Fruits to Vegetables).Shown below is the code for Vegetable.scala

```
package com.att.scala
import java.awt.Color

trait Vegetable {
  val name: String
  val color: Color
}

object Vegetables {
   object Asparagus extends Vegetable { } 
   object Shallot extends Vegetable { }
   object Cauliflower extends Vegetable { }
   object Spinach extends Vegetable { }
   val veggiePlatter = List(Asparagus, Shallot)
}
```

---

These are my findings:
Eclipse does not want to compile this code. It says: "object creation impossible, since: value color in trait Vegetable of type java.awt.Color is not defined value name in trait Vegetable of type String is not defined"

What I hope to accomplish from this code is to understand why this error occurs. How can I make Vegetable available to object Asparagus, Shallot and Cauliflower? My rather (naive) understanding at this point is that since Vegetable and Vegetables occur in the same package and in the same source file, trait Vegetable should be visible to object Asparagus (which extends Vegetable) for example.

Is there something specific about a trait that I need to know before I even use a trait in this manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the implementation of your objects. This should work:

```
package com.att.scala
import java.awt.Color

trait Vegetable {
  val name: String
  val color: Color
}

object Vegetables {
   object Asparagus extends Vegetable { 
       name = "Asparagus"
       color = new Color(255,255,255)
   } 
   //...
}
```

val declarations without a value are similar to abstract methods in Java in that they need an 'implementation' i.e. a value.

Comment: white asparagus (that I usually see canned). always freaked me out a bit.  I suggest something more like Color(135, 169, 107).  Otherwise, solid answer! :)

Comment: I see it now. The way I understand it after you explained it: A trait is roughly equivalent to a Java abstract class. Extending that logic, we need an implementation (value) for  those vals in trait Vegetable, because if we did not have the implementation, creating object Asparagus is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not one of visibility - it does not compile because `Asparagus` etc do not provide values for the fields that `extends Vegetable` requires them to. Each of those objects that you want to `extends Vegetable` must supply a `name` and `color` value.

The following compiles just fine:

```
trait Vegetable {
    val name: String
    val color: String
}

object Vegetables {
    object Asparagus extends Vegetable {
        val name = "Asparagus"
        val color = "Green"
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not one of visibility at all. That makes sense now. All answers are great and I am at a loss which one to choose as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, you haven't provided any values for the name or color variables defined in your trait.

You could either provide a default value, like:

```
trait Vegetable {
  val name: String = "Some Vegetable"
  val color: Color = Color.GREEN
}
```

However that would produce the same value for each object unless you override it. To define for each object, you'd need to do something like:

```
object Asparagus extends Vegetable { 
  val name = "Asparagus"
  val color = Color.GREEN
}
```

Comment: You are right. That is the whole problem that I have not been seeing at all, until you explained it to me. My gratitude.